# a way that most people think {is / it is} wrong

Tags: relative-clauses, resumptive-pronouns

I was reading definition/meaning of the word "perverse" in [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/perverse), came across :

> showing deliberate determination to behave in a way that most people **think is wrong, unacceptable or unreasonable**

Shouldn't it be :

> showing deliberate determination to behave in a way that most people think **it** is wrong, unacceptable or unreasonable

Comment: Actually your rewrite is incorrect. Adding "it" there is wrong. I can explain, but I need some time before I post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *it* is unncessary.

You understand correctly that there is an empty 'slot' in the sentence—the subject of the clause *is wrong &c*.

There are two ways of looking at what's going on:

- In traditional grammar the *that* is understood to be a "relative pronoun" which 'stands for' a "referent" or "antecedent", *way*, and acts as the displaced subject of *is wrong &c*
- Many contemporary grammars call the *that* a "relativizer", a sort of variable which points backward toward the referent, the variable's 'value', and forward toward an empty slot ("gap" or "trace"); it instructs the hearer or reader to find the gap and fill it with the value.

The two analyses amount to pretty much the same thing: that empty slot is a feature, not a bug; StackExchange would tag it [by-design](/questions/tagged/by-design).

It is not ungrammatical to fill the gap with *it* as you do; this happens frequently in speech. (Grammarians call it a *resumptive pronoun*, one which 'resumes' mention of the referent.) However, it is redundant, and is deprecated in writing.

Comment: @StoneyB I understood your explanation, and agree completely with it, except one thing. That is my confusion here. I thought filling the gap there is ungrammatical. For example if we consider the following sentence - *The parents **who** we interviewed were all involved in education in some way.* - there is also a gap (*the missing object of **interviewed***). As you said it's a feature, but there if we try to fill it. it will be ungrammatical. Isn't it? OP's sentence here is also similar. right?

Comment: @Man_From_India There's grammatical and there's grammatical. It shouldn't be used in writing, but you'll often hear it colloquially, especially when a lot of words intervene between the referent and the relative.

Comment: @StoneyB Ah I see... You already mentioned it in your answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: @StoneyB, Man, Yes, the length of the clause definitely affect it's acceptability. "***I don't like that story that you wrote it***" would be taken as ungrammatical by most, at least over here.

Comment: @Man_From_India But in speech, where people construct utterances by progressive accretion rather than careful subordination, you're very likely to hear "That story about the woman locked up in the room with the yellow wallpaper and she goes crazier and crazier which I think Charlotte something Gilman wrote it, I really liked that one."